# Why is GNU parallel Quicksort so slow compared to Mergesort?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, gnu, quicksort

I have been testing the practicality of OpenMP GNU parallel sort algorithms in the C++ standard library and have found the parallel Quicksort algorithm to be significantly slower than the Mergesort algorithm. On my PC, Mergesort would take 52 seconds to sort a vector of 8 billion integers, whilst Quicksort would take just under 8 minutes. Unscientific inspection of its CPU usage showed that the quicksort made full use of parallelism in the for about 20 seconds and then the rest of its run just used 2 threads (or %200 CPU).

I checked the source code for the algorithm and, whilst I could not understand all of it. If this is not the reason, could someone perhaps explain to me why the algorithm is so slow in contrast to mergesort? I had thought of contacting the original author of the algorithm, but considered it politer to at try here first.

Here is some code which hopefully demonstrates the problem, you can specify on the command line how many elements to sort if you do not have insane amounts of resources required for my run. I am using GCC 4.9:

```
#include <vector>
#include <parallel/algorithm>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sstream>

const size_t DEFAULT_NUMBER = 8000000000;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t number_of_elements = DEFAULT_NUMBER;
    if(argc > 1 && argv[1] != 0)
    {   
        number_of_elements = atoi(argv[1]);
    }   
    std::vector<int> elements(number_of_elements);
    srandom(10);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++)
    {   
        elements[i] = random();
    }   

    boost::posix_time::ptime time = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
    __gnu_parallel::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), __gnu_parallel::multiway_mergesort_tag());
    std::cout << "Mergesort took: " << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time() - time) <<  std::endl;

    //Repopulate vector with random elements
    srandom(10);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++)
    {   
        elements[i] = random();
    }   
    time = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
    __gnu_parallel::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), __gnu_parallel::quicksort_tag());
    std::cout << "Quicksort took: " << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time() - time) <<  std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I would suspect because of pagination and memory usage patterns. Did you try to run experiments with different vector sizes and see how performances vary?

Comment: I think because the QuickSort works with the same array all the time, so threads need to be serialized to access the array. The MergeSort makes copies of the array halves, sorts them and then merges them, so the data access serialization is not needed.

Comment: @Svalorzen The data I tried was with a billion elements, 2 billion, 4 billion. 1 Billion elements was 9 seconds for Mergesort and 54 seconds for Quicksort, so the gap does widen.

Comment: @user3751940 Did you try with 1k, 10k, 100k, and so on in the millions? It does not make much sense to start up in the billions, you know. You need to see the whole picture.

Comment: what is your memory size?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/parallel_mode_using.html#parallel_mode.using.prereq_flags). I used options:

```
CFLAGS += -fopenmp -Ofast -march=native
```

They accelerate your test, but sorry to say I don't have enough cores to reproduce your results. Anyway, allowing native CPU operations should affect data access serialization.

Comment: I spent a fair amount of time reading it. The information about Sort and its tags seemed inconsistent with the compilation errors I was getting. Anyway, I originally optimized via -O2, I added your options but got no meaningful performance benefits.

Comment: What kind of machine/OS do you run on?

Comment: I still can't reproduce your result - on my machine the QuickSort (especially the `balanced_quicksort` version) works faster than the MergeSort (sorting 4 billions of bytes). However, I see the effect you are talking about in the Task Manager - CPU #1 is 100%, CPU #2 is 50%. Probably it's because of the limited number of threads, used in the conquer step - I see the `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)` in both versions of the QuickSort.

Comment: I am using a dual Intel Xeon E5-2670 (16 physical cores total) with CentOS 6.4. I have 120GB RAM, so I an understand if you would find it hard to reproduce my results. I checked the code and saw this, but I must have missed it on the non-stable sort. If the aforementioned thread limiter is the cause, why would one deliberately do this during the conquer stage? I guess you are right as in your comment for my question?